# what is the decisive difference between mutex and condition variables?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, mutex, condition-variable

I read several posts (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551341/when-is-a-condition-variable-needed-isnt-a-mutex-enough)) on stackoverflow about the difference but none of them give a clear explanation.

Wonder what's the scenario that requires the use of the one instead of the other and why?

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the concept, I realize the decisive difference.

A mutex provides mutual exclusive semantics, which a thread blocks on another thread which is in a critical section. On the other hand, a conditional variable doesn't require **another thread**. It's a condition that a thread blocks on.

Take a producer/consumer queue for example. If the queue is empty, a consumer will block on this condition instead of on another producer/consumer thread.